# Bing API 7 - SimilarProducts module and site filtering

Tags: bing

Working on an updated application to query the SimilarProducts module based on an image stream. I'm trying to limit the product results for a single site. The following query seems to ignore this limit:

https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/details?q=site:mydomain.com&modules=SimilarProducts&mkt=en-us

I can dig a bit further, just wondering if there is a limitation to using them together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Bing Visual Search API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/) for this purpose. It supports **site:** parameter. Bing Image Search API doesn't support this parameter.

Comment: This? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bingvisualsearch/images/visualsearch...I reviewed the documentation but didn't see anything about the query param. Also tried https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/visualsearch?q=site:mydomain.com but results didn't appear limited.

Comment: I meant to say use the Bing Visual Search endpoint in the same way you are using the Image Search endpoint. Check out this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/overview and see site filter.